# Twitter api response object details

Tags: api, twitter, response

When I call twitter API "friendships/show" it show me response object, but there is no any response details available even in twitter api page.

Is any body have idea about the details of following parameters?

"live_following": false,
"following_received": false,
"following_requested": false,
"notifications_enabled": false,
"all_replies": false,
"marked_spam": false